# Do vlookup until blank cell

Tags: vba, vlookup

I have been trying to fix this problem for weeks.  I have a template that has a user form. This user form selects the current month report and previous months report and runs a vlookup in the current month report. It runs the vlookup in column B. Problem is, the code runs vlookup and doesn't stop, I need it to stop as soon as it hits a blank cell in column C. 
Here is the code. I am in dire need of help here. Thank you!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim str1 As String
    Dim str2 As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
            str1 = ListBox1.List(i)
        End If
    Next i

    For i = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox2.Selected(i) = True Then
            str2 = ListBox2.List(i)
        End If
    Next i

    Workbooks(str1).Activate
    Sheets(1).Activate
    Range("B1").Select
    i = 0
    Do Until ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Value = "Category"
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    Range("B1").Offset(i, 0).Select
    With Range(ActiveCell.Offset(1), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 2))
        .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(C" & ActiveCell.Offset(1).Row & ",'[" & str2 & "]Sheet1'!$A$4:$B$200,2,FALSE)"
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps...

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim lMacroSec As MsoAutomationSecurity
    Dim lCalc As XlCalculation
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    With Application
        lMacroSec = .AutomationSecurity
        lCalc = .Calculation
        .AutomationSecurity = lMacroSec
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
            For j = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
                If ListBox2.Selected(j) = True Then
                    With Workbooks(ListBox1.List(i)).Sheets(1)
                        With .Columns("B").Find("Category").Offset(1)
                            With .Parent.Range(.Cells, .Offset(-1, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(, -1))
                                .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(C" & .Row & ",'[" & ListBox2.List(j) & "]Sheet1'!$A$4:$B$200,2,FALSE)"
                                .Calculate
                            End With
                        End With
                    End With
                End If
            Next j
        End If
    Next i

    With Application
        .AutomationSecurity = lMacroSec
        .Calculation = lCalc
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for trying to help me. There is a problem with the line ".Close True". 3rd row from the actual vlookup. ???

Comment: Oh, right, should be `.Parent.Close True` I'll update the answer

Comment: That helped. But 2 things - the vlookup does not stop if there is a blank cell in column C. It's doing what my macro did. Also, can the current month report not close after the macro runs? Thank you so much

Comment: So where there is a blank in column C, do you want that row skipped? Or just stop there?  As for not closing, remove the `.Parent.Close True` line.  That is what is closing the opened workbook, which I'm guessing is the "current month report"

Comment: I need it to stop when it hits a blank cell in column C. I did remove .Parent.Close True and I am still getting errors.

Comment: Updated code to stop when it hits a blank cell in column C.  If you're getting errors, what is the error message and what line is highlighted when you click Debug?

Comment: Error reads:run time error 1004. Application defined or object defined error. it highlights  With .Range(.Columns("B").Find("Category").Offset(1))

Comment: Oh, oops, remove the outer .Range(), so that the line is: `.Columns("B").Find("Category").Offset(1)`  I have updated the answer with this correction.

Comment: It is there. In the current month's report in Column B. The code worked a few minutes ago before I deleted parent.close.

Comment: Is there a way for me to upload a screenshot?

Comment: It's close. But now it is doing a vlookup in column B and C. It just needs to be in Column B.

Comment: Looks like I had a mistake in the section with .End(xlDown), I forgot to offset it back to the left 1, I have corrected this in the updated code.  It's really hard when I don't have any sample data, lol

Comment: Believe me, I know. I tried attaching the spreadsheets here, but I can't. I am so grateful for how much you have already helped me. Now there is a syntax error with this line   With .Parent.Range(.Cells, .Offset(-1, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(, -1)

Comment: The line needed one more closing parenthesis at the very end `.Offset(, -1))`  I have updated the code again

Comment: WOW WOW WOW WOW it works!!!!! I owe you a giant box of chocolates! Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Hello, tigeravatar, I was wondering if you could help me with a few more things regarding this code because a few different variables came into play this week. 1. Every month sheet1 tab name changes. Right now, the vlookup code selects only "sheet1", can it select sheet1 (whatever the new name is every month in that tab) ?

Comment: 2. Can the following code be inserted into your code BEFORE the code looks for the word "CATEGORY" in current month's report in ListBox1?     Range("A4").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("B4").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("B3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("C3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ID's" Range("D9").Select

Comment: 3. Can this code be pasted into your code AFTER the vlookup is completed? This copy and paste is for the current month's report which is the report that would be selected in Listbox1.                                                                Range("C3").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

Comment: any chance you could help me with these 3 more steps mentioned above to your macro? Thank you

Comment: Can someone please help me with this? This project is due very soon and I can't figure this out. Thank you.